# Matplotlib: create multiple subplot in one figure

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, matplotlib

I have a data frame has columns `x1, x2, x3, x4, x5, x6, my_y`. I am making a scatter plot for each xi ~ y like:

```
%matplotlib notebook
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib
matplotlib.style.use('ggplot')
my_df.plot(x='x1', y='my_y', kind = 'scatter', marker = 'x', color = 'black', ylim = [0, 10])
```

I repeated the above code 6 times for `x1, x2, x3, x4, x5, x6`, to create 6 figures. I am wondering if it possible to make one figure with 6 scatter subplots? Thanks!

Comment: What happens if you do `x=['x1', 'x2', 'x3', 'x4', 'x5', 'x6']`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
df = pd.DataFrame(
    np.random.randint(10, size=(5, 7)),
    columns='x1 x2 x3 x4 x5 x6 my_y'.split()
)

df

   x1  x2  x3  x4  x5  x6  my_y
0   0   8   3   2   7   5     8
1   0   6   2   5   8   4     9
2   4   7   1   2   6   4     5
3   8   5   4   0   5   7     4
4   5   6   0   1   8   7     2
```

---

**Option1**
Use the `scatter` method from the `axes` elements.

```
fig, axes = plt.subplots(2, 3, figsize=(6, 4), sharex=True, sharey=True)
y = df.my_y.values
for i in range(6):
    axes[i//3, i%3].scatter(df.iloc[:, i].values, y)

fig.tight_layout()
```

[image]

---

**Option 2**
Use `pandas.DataFrame.plot`

```
fig, axes = plt.subplots(2, 3, figsize=(6, 4), sharex=True, sharey=True)
y = df.my_y.values
for i in range(6):
    df.plot(x='x' + str(i+1),
            y='my_y',
            kind='scatter',
            marker='x',
            color='black',
            ylim=[0, 10],
            ax=axes[i//3, i%3])

fig.tight_layout()
```

[image]

---

**Response to Comment**
Without `sharex=True`

```
fig, axes = plt.subplots(2, 3, figsize=(6, 4), sharey=True)
y = df.my_y.values
for i in range(6):
    df.plot(x='x' + str(i+1),
            y='my_y',
            kind='scatter',
            marker='x',
            color='black',
            ylim=[0, 10],
            ax=axes[i//3, i%3])

fig.tight_layout()
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks! Also wondering when using the option 2, is it possible to have the x-axis label (x1, x2, x3) for the first row subplots?

Comment: Turn off my `sharex=True`