# Why can't I plot multiple scatter subplots in one figure for a data set from a DataFrame of Pandas (Python) in the way I plot subplots of histograms?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, matplotlib, dataframe

I am learning how to play with matplotlib recently. However, some problems come up. I read in a non-standard data file named students.data with the following command.

```
student_dataset = pd.read_csv("students.data", index_col=0)
```

Here is how students.data looks like.

[image]

Then I plot a figure with four subplots of histograms in it with the following commands.

```
fig = plt.figure(0) #Use it to create subplots.
fig.subplots_adjust(hspace=0.5, wspace=0.5) #Adjust height-spacing to 
                                            #de-overlap titles and ticks

ax1 = fig.add_subplot(2, 2, 1)
my_series1 = student_dataset["G1"]
my_series1.plot.hist(alpha=0.5, color = "blue", histtype = "bar", bins = 30)

ax2 = fig.add_subplot(2, 2, 2)
my_series2 = student_dataset["G2"]
my_series2.plot.hist(alpha=1, color = "green", histtype = "step", bins = 20)

ax3 = fig.add_subplot(2, 2, 3)
my_series3 = student_dataset["G3"]
my_series3.plot.hist(alpha=0.5, color = "red", histtype = "stepfilled")

ax4 = fig.add_subplot(2, 2, 4)
my_series1.plot.hist(alpha=0.5, color = "blue")
my_series2.plot.hist(alpha=0.5, color = "green")
my_series3.plot.hist(alpha=0.5, color = "red")
```

And the result is exactly the stuff I want. However, as I try to do so for scatter subplots, they are separated in different figures. And I cannot figure out why. Here are the commands.

```
fig = plt.figure(2)
ax1 = fig.add_subplot(2, 2, 1)
student_dataset.plot.scatter(x = "freetime", y = "G1")

ax2 = fig.add_subplot(2, 2, 2)
student_dataset.plot.scatter(x = "freetime", y = "G2")

ax3 = fig.add_subplot(2, 2, 3)
student_dataset.plot.scatter(x = "freetime", y = "G3")
```

After searching for a day, I find [the solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45493053/matplotlib-create-multiple-subplot-in-one-figure) that almost fits my target. But, still, why? Why my original method is not working?

Here are the new commands and the result.

```
fig, axes = plt.subplots(2, 2, figsize=(6, 6), sharex=False, sharey=False)

x = student_dataset["freetime"].values
for i in range(3):
    axes[i//2, i%2].scatter(x, student_dataset.iloc[:, i + 25].values)

fig.tight_layout()
```

Sorry that I cannot put more images in this post to describe my question. Hope you can understand my point.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may choose to use option 2 of the linked question,

```
fig = plt.figure(2)
ax1 = fig.add_subplot(2, 2, 1)
student_dataset.plot.scatter(x = "freetime", y = "G1", ax=ax1)

ax2 = fig.add_subplot(2, 2, 2)
student_dataset.plot.scatter(x = "freetime", y = "G2", ax=ax2)

ax3 = fig.add_subplot(2, 2, 3)
student_dataset.plot.scatter(x = "freetime", y = "G3", ax=ax3)
```

If you don't specify `ax`, pandas will produce a new figure.

At the moment I don't have any good explanation for why `plot.hist` does not require the `ax` keyword; it probably has to do with it directly calling the `plt.hist` function instead of preprocessing the data first.

Comment: Thanks a ton. It really works. I will notice about this next time I use it. : )

Comment: If this is indeed the solution to your problem, I think we can mark this as duplicate.

Comment: Yeah, sure, you could do so.